# Importing a function from a sibling folder in python producing strange errors

Tags: python, function, import, module, relative-import

I'm have a script 'zigbot.py' which was working, but I'm restructuring to dockerize and now I'm questioning my ability to code at all. What I'm trying to do is have a telegram-bot container, and a 'web' container (FLASK), and a nginx container.

Next to zigbot.py I have a folder - 'bot', which has many of my scripts and functions in. Upon trying `from bot.somescript import a_function` I am getting error after error.

Project structure

```
zigbot
    bot
        bot
            __init__.py
            conversations.py
            ct.py
            Docerfile
            funcs.py
            pricedata.py
            requirements.txt
            util.py
        zigbot.py
    nginx
        somestuff
    web
        app
            migrations
            templates
            __init__.py
            config.py
            forms.py
            functions.py
            models.py
            routes.py
            signals.py
        __init__.py
        Dockerfile
        requirements.txt
        zigweb.py
```

When running the code below, I get a whole range of strange errors - the one listed below shows ImportError - it can't find 'onboard' in funcs, but its definitely there. Before the restructure, this was working. If I comment out 'onboard' it errors on every function in the list.

```
from bot.conversations import key_conversation
from bot.crypto_functions import satoshi_to_btc
from bot.funcs import onboard, main_menu, new_message1, new_keyboard, onboarded_keyboard, \
    onboarded_message, blank_signal_message, send_signal_format, get_or_create_user, signal_detected_keyboard, log_me
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zigbot.py", line 15, in <module>
    from bot.funcs import onboard, main_menu, new_message1, new_keyboard, onboarded_keyboard, \
  File "ZigBot\bot\bot\funcs.py", line 2, in <module>
    from zigbot.web.app import db, app
  File "ZigBot\bot\zigbot.py", line 15, in <module>
    from bot.funcs import onboard, main_menu, new_message1, new_keyboard, onboarded_keyboard, \
ImportError: cannot import name 'onboard'
```

So I tried adding a .bot.conversation for (relative?) import, but this produces an even weirder error. I've included the code, the error, then the function I'm trying to import below:

```
from .bot.conversations import key_conversation
from .bot.crypto_functions import satoshi_to_btc
from .bot.funcs import onboard, main_menu, new_message1, new_keyboard, onboarded_keyboard, \
    onboarded_message, blank_signal_message, send_signal_format, get_or_create_user, signal_detected_keyboard, log_me
from ..web.app import db
from ..web.app.models import User, Signal
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zigbot.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .bot.conversations import key_conversation
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.bot'; '__main__' is not a package
```

conversations.py

```
# Initialise conversationHandler states
def key_conversation(cancel):
    # Define keyboards
    keyboard = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton('Previous', callback_data='onboard:key'),
         InlineKeyboardButton('Next', callback_data='onboard:alldone')]]
    conversation_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
```

Finally, I think I'm getting closer to the problem, I go back to the way I think it's supposed to be imported. From bot.funcs import x,y,y... I look in funcs.py and this is how its importing some other code from my Flask web app, but it doesn't like it.

funcs.py

```
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from web.app import db, app
from web.app.models import User
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zigbot.py", line 15, in <module>
    from bot.funcs import onboard, main_menu, new_message1, new_keyboard, onboarded_keyboard, \
  File "ZigBot\bot\bot\funcs.py", line 2, in <module>
    from web.app import db, app
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'web'
```

So I change the import to go up a level since web is two levels above `bot` - which contains the script I'm importing to. So `zigbot>bot>bot>funcs.py` trying to import from `zigbot>web>app>`

```
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from ..web.app import db, app
from ..web.app.models import User
import telegram
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zigbot.py", line 15, in <module>
    from bot.funcs import onboard, main_menu, new_message1, new_keyboard, onboarded_keyboard, \
  File "\ZigBot\bot\bot\funcs.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ..web.app import db, app
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

This obviously doesn't work either. Given my structure of having `bot` and `web` how do I get this to work? I even tried pulling the scripts out of the second 'bot' folder but I get the same issues. Finally, my weirdest error which might provide a clue to what I'm doing wrong, if I change the import on funcs.py to go one level up, rather than two, I get an even stranger traceback.

```
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from .web.app import db, app
from .web.app.models import User
import telegram
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zigbot.py", line 15, in <module>
    from bot.funcs import onboard, main_menu, new_message1, new_keyboard, onboarded_keyboard, \
  File "C:\Users\phill\PycharmProjects\ZigBot\bot\bot\funcs.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .web.app import db, app
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bot.web'
```

For clarity I removed some 'C:\Users\phill' from the tracebacks before realising it was pointless to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a fundamental flaw in your split if you have library dependencies across the boundary. Assuming that there are no imports of bot-modules in your web container, I would suggest breaking off the shared code into a module named `weblib` or something (alongside the `bot`-, `nginx`- and `web`-folders).

You still should not try to import across would-be container boundaries however, so just make sure `weblib` is in your path or installed in your virtual environment or however you want to handle it. Basically, `bot` and `web` should run in separate environments and should have `weblib` as a dependency.

Someone wiser than me might be able to explain it better.

Comment: My `bot` is sending data to the `web` app's database, so it's basically importing Flask's models and trying to write to them....?

Comment: Since you did not mention a separate container for the database, I assume it will live in the `web` app's container. In that case you should probably let that app handle the database on it's own and send the data to it as HTTP requests. Alternatively, you could have the database in a container on it's own, in which case the models should live in a neutral library as previously suggested.

Answer (score 0):

For relative imports to work all the packages and subpackages must be in the sys.path - to achieve this you should run from the top-level directory as in:

```
C:\Users\phill\zigbot>python -m bot.zigbot
```

This will make your current working dir (zigbot) available to sys.path and the subpackages will be resolved correctly